# Работа с 2captcha.com | c#

Tags: c#, post, request, captcha, recaptcha

Здравствуйте. Возникла проблема с работой 2captcha.com
Метод работы с сервисом: **base64**
Отправляю пост запрос:
**method=base64&key={*api_key*}&base64={*base64string*}**
Проблема в том, что на сервере судя по всему картинка не отображается: правильного ответа не пришло ни разу. Приходили ответы вида "empty" или "white".
Так же много раз был ответ сервера **ERROR_CAPTCHA_UNSOLVABLE**
Пожалуйста, те, кто работал на шарпе с сервисом - помогите. В чем проблема?

Comment: Это значит, что люди решавшие для вас капчи, пометили их как "пустую", "белую", или "нерешаемую". Смотрите на изображения, которые отправляете - возможно они действительно "пустые", "белые", или "нерешаемые"

Comment: @SergeyRufanov благодарю за ответ. Не могу понять почему они все таки пустые. Я отправлял данные себе на локаль: $_POST['base64'] не пустая. Кроме того пробовал декодировать ее обратно в картинку - все было ок.